# How to get the location of center dot in Google Cardboard in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

How do I get the location of center dot in Google Cardboard in Unity3D? I'd like to shoot a cannonball at this center dot when a player pushes the button, but I need to find the direction of the vector that represents this dot.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use ray casting to achieve this, please check these links:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/raycasting
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer. I know the starting point, but I don't know how to find the direction of where I want to shoot. The center dot.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use `Camera.main.transform.forward`

```
 // create the bullet object from the bullet prefab
 var bullet = (GameObject)Instantiate(bulletPrefab, Camera.main.transform.position - Camera.main.transform.forward, Quaternion.identity);

 // make the bullet move away in front of the player
 bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Camera.main.transform.forward * 4;
```